# WebStorm. How to add spaces within interpolation expressions ('{{' and '}}') in html file?

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have a template in html file that contains a lot of interpolation expressions.

```
<td>{{product.productName}}</td>
```

How can I edit my Code Style rules in WebStorm to make it looks like this after **Ctrl+Alt+L**?

```
<td>{{ product.productName }}</td>
```

I am already check option **Within interpolation expressions** in *Preferences -> Editor -> Code style -> TypeScript*, but this is affects only **.ts** files.

Answer (score 4):

Try enabling it for javascript - **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Spaces**, **Other/Within interpolation expressions**

Comment: reproduced, submitted as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31573

Comment: In latest WebStorm two checkboxes in TypeScript and JavaScript for interpolations works for me. (using Angular 5, html interpolation works)